# Converting float to varchar with correct decimal separator

Tags: sql-server-2008, decimal-point

Hi i'm living in austria and we use the `,` as decimal separator.

It seems to be impossible to convert the float to varchar with the correct separator according to the language/collation setting?

Is this a bug?

```
set language german --makes no difference in this case
declare @f float = 4.5
select @f --output in my management studio is 4,5 
          --according to the regional os settings this is correct

select convert(varchar,@f) -- output: 4.5 not correct
```

one solution, but not ideal I think

```
select replace(convert(varchar,@f),'.',',')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- SSMS formats the `float` type based on your `regional` settings
- The SQL Engine language setting doesn't affect what separators are used

Correctly, you should leave numbers as numbers and format in the client. 
This is what SSMS is doing for you

Also see [SQL server with german regional settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1229147/27535)

Comment: Thats true, thanks,
but you can convert DateTime with different styles, why not the decimal seperator?

So i still think its a bug (or a missing feature) :)