# Conversion float and decimal in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting float to varchar with correct decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310007/converting-float-to-varchar-with-correct-decimal-separator)

When I run: `select convert(float, 10.12), convert(decimal(5, 2), 10.12)`
I get this result:

```
(No column name)    (No column name)
10,12   10.12
```

Why is this happening? I'm from Brazil and my Windows language is set to Portuguese, but shouldn't both decimal and float return '.' or ',' at same time?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed as duplicate.  The linked question is regarding why the language setting does not influence the decimal separator in a float conversion.  You question is specifically about why the float and decimal types do not use the same decimal separator when using convert.  Nevertheless, I hope my answer helped!

Comment: Thanks Jason, it surely did. I was looking for a way around, but your link shows that it's a problem with SQL Server itself. Unfortunately, all I can do is convert to varchar and use REPLACE() to replace ',' with '.' and convert to decimal later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the issue, but it appears to be a fomatting bug in SSMS.  It uses the OS regional setting for float and money, but not for decimal.

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/458416/microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-doesnt-get-os-regional-setting