# Inconsistent DATETIME/FLOAT conversion with CONVERT when user language not English

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, localization

I have some trouble with SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 when working with values which have a different representation in German than in English. Server and OS are running as German versions.

```
SET LANGUAGE deutsch;
SELECT 
    CONVERT(datetime, '31. Dezember 1999') as a, 
    CONVERT(nvarchar, CONVERT(datetime, '31. Dezember 1999')) as b, 
    CONVERT(float,'3.14159') as p,
    CONVERT(nvarchar, CONVERT(float,'3.14159')) as q;
```

the output in the management console is this:

```
a=1999-12-31 00:00:00.000   
b=Dez 31 1999 12:00AM
c=3,14159   
d=3.14159
dateformat=dmy
```

This is inconsistent. In (a) the *German* representation of Dec-31-1999 is correctly parsed and displayed (and only German works..). Converting the same date explicitly with CONVERT returns a string which mixes an *English* date format with a *German* abbreviated month name (it says "Dez 31" not "Dec 31" if you look closely).

But p is converted from a string in *English* notation (decimal point) into a float, yet displayed in *German* notation (using a decimal comma), while explicit conversion to nvarchar yields the number in *English* notation again. OTOH CONVERT() does not accept input in German notation for conversion to float.

So, I have a CONVERT function:

1. which accepts strings for conversion to datetime in *German* notation only.
2. but accepts strings for conversion to float in *English* only.
3. and converts datetime values to nvarchar mixing both *German and English*.
4. converts float values to *English*.

But what I need is a function in SQL Server 2005, 2008 which converts text from the current user language to values of the supported types (datetime, floats...) and converts these values back into a text representation with respect to the current user language.

What is this function?

Comment: The solution for dates is to pass proper, unambiguous formats like `19991231` - this is the same date in any language.

Answer (score 1):

[SET LANGUAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx)

> [s]pecifies the language environment for the session. The session
>   language determines the datetime formats and system messages.

Setting the style parameter of the [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function 120 supports language-independent conversion.

As for the conversion of float values, have a look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310007/converting-float-to-varchar-witch-correct-decimal-separator) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229147/sql-server-with-german-regional-settings).

Generally, you should avoid language-specific formatting in the database, and implement it in the UI.